# Правильная грамматика на русском языке

Tags: орфография

*Осталась 1 штука* — правильно ли так? Или *осталось 1 штука?*

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, так правильно: *остал**а**сь одна штука.* Глагол должен согласоваться по роду со словом "штука" ***женского*** рода.